# Specifying an image size when posting image to Facebook

Tags: c#, facebook-graph-api, facebook-c#-sdk

I am using the C# FaceBook API to post a status update and an image to a wall. I am using the following code:

```
    public string PostToFaceBookPage(string appKey, string appSecret, string wallId, string postMessage, string imageUrl)
    {
        string id = "";
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(imageUrl))
            imageUrl = "";
        var client = new Facebook.FacebookClient();

        dynamic result = client.Post("oauth/access_token",
                                      new
                                      {
                                          client_id = appKey,
                                          client_secret = appSecret,
                                          grant_type = "client_credentials",
                                          redirect_uri = "anywhere",
                                          scope = "publish_stream"
                                      });
        client.AccessToken = (result)["access_token"];

        if (!IsId(wallId))
        {
            result = client.Get(wallId);
            id = result["id"];
        } else
        {
            id = wallId;
        }

        if (imageUrl == "")
        {
            result = client.Post("/" + id + "/feed", new
                {
                    message = postMessage,
                    scope = "publish_stream",
                    privacy = "{\"value\": \"EVERYONE\"}"
                });
        } else
        {
            var uri = new Uri(imageUrl);
            string imageName = Path.GetFileName(uri.LocalPath);
            string mimeType = GetMimeType(Path.GetExtension(uri.LocalPath));
            var media = new Facebook.FacebookMediaObject
                {
                    FileName = imageName,
                    ContentType = mimeType
                };

            media.SetValue(GetImage(imageUrl));
            result = client.Post("/" + id + "/feed", new
            {
                message = postMessage,
                source = media,
                picture = imageUrl,
                scope = "publish_stream",
                privacy = "{\"value\": \"EVERYONE\"}"
            });
        }

        return "";
    }
```

Everything is working just fine. My only problem is that my images are all posting the same exact size, regardless of the size of the actual image. Is there a way to tell FaceBook the size of the image so it doesn't just post small thumbnails of the image?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if Facebook API can have these parameters as it has been a few years since I have worked with the API.

As a temporary fix however, you could try resizing the photo before uploading it to facebook.

You can use the below code from http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/csharp-tutorial-image-editing-saving-cropping-and-resizing

```
private static Image resizeImage(Image imgToResize, Size size)
{
   int sourceWidth = imgToResize.Width;
   int sourceHeight = imgToResize.Height;

   float nPercent = 0;
   float nPercentW = 0;
   float nPercentH = 0;

   nPercentW = ((float)size.Width / (float)sourceWidth);
   nPercentH = ((float)size.Height / (float)sourceHeight);

   if (nPercentH < nPercentW)
      nPercent = nPercentH;
   else
      nPercent = nPercentW;

   int destWidth = (int)(sourceWidth * nPercent);
   int destHeight = (int)(sourceHeight * nPercent);

   Bitmap b = new Bitmap(destWidth, destHeight);
   Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage((Image)b);
   g.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;

   g.DrawImage(imgToResize, 0, 0, destWidth, destHeight);
   g.Dispose();

   return (Image)b;
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment. My images are already resized correctly. The problem is, somewhere in Facebook's Graph API, its scaling it down. i'm thinking there is some kind parameter I need to pass to specify the size. By not specifying the size, I think Facebook it just automatically sizing it to the smallest size by default.

Comment: Ah. As far as I know/remember about Facebook, the image is always shrunk to fit their image size limits for feed posts, so there may be no way around it.

If anyone knows different, i'd like to know :)